# Making coefficients positive in a linear inequality constraint.

Tags: inequality, optimization, linear-programming, discrete-optimization

Suppose with have linear inequality constraints $q_i^Tx \leq c_i$ with $q_i \in \mathbb{Z}^n$ for $i=1,\ldots,m$ and $x \in \{0,1\}^n$.

I would like to know if it is possible to reformulate $q_i^Tx \leq c_i$ into something like $p_i^T y \leq c'_i$ where $p_i \geq 0$ (all coefficients are positive or zero) and $y \in \{0,1\}^n$. If yes, how would one do that?

I suspect it is not possible... but maybe there are some tricks or workarounds to address this issue at least partially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $q_{ij}<0$, replace $x_j$ with $1-y_j$, take $p_{ij}=-q_{ij}$, and adjust $c_i$ by subtracting $q_{ij}$.

Comment: Hi Rob, thank you so much! I would like to clarify one thing. The above works for the constraint $i$ with the variable $j$. Will this still work if there is another constraint $i_0$ where the coefficients $q_{i_0j} >0$? Do I just keep $x_i$ unchanged for the $i_0$ constraint?

Comment: @MonteNero: I wonder if using both $x_j$ and $y_j$ ( with condition $x_j + y_j =1$) is acceptable